# Highcharts tooltip stock color change

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the color showed on the left of the stock name in the candlestick chart , BUT when edit color: in the series, it also changes the color of my candlestick chart, I want to have different color for every stock but to keep the same color in the chart. Any possible ways of doing this?

[image]

Comment: You can use the `formatter` function in your tooltip, and reference an external array of colors that you want to use for each stock.

Comment: as jlbriggs mentioned, use formatter, pointFormatter or pointFormat properties to change color. http://jsfiddle.net/9ey7m11r/